# AWS S3 and Cloudfront CDN for video files

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm just getting started using AWS S3 and Cloudfront service. 
So far I've created a S3 instance and a Node.js server which streams the files from S3 to the user reaching the server's endpoint.

```
const params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: KEY
 };  
const obj = s3.getObject(params);
const stream = obj.createReadStream()
stream.pipe(res); // RES is the result send back to user
```

From my understanding, you get a CDN for your files, if you spin up a CloudFront distribution so my next step was to add Cloudfront to my S3 bucket.

My next action was to add the endpoint to the S3 instance in the code:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  endpoint: CLOUDFRONT_URL
})
```

Now however I get the following error when people reach the endpoint:

> UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host:
>   BUCKET_NAME.CLOUDFRONT_URL. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region.

It seems from the error message, Cloudfront is not available in the US-EAST region which seems weird to me? I'm thinking I just made a mistake configuring it in the code. Any advice?

**Edit:**

My use case is as follows:

I have an app that allow downloads of video content. These videos are stored on AWS S3. Since people from all over the world are accessing these videos, my idea was to enable Cloudfront on the bucket to make downloads available at servers closer to the user and therefore getting better download speed.

Currently the user ask the endpoint to download a file and the Node.js server streams the video file from S3 to the user.

I might have misunderstood the use case for Cloudfront.

Comment: It looks wrong to me, you cannot use CloudFront URL when making S3 API Calls. You're making S3 GETobject API call and this won't work on CloudFront URL, CloudFront works on simple HTTP request, just make a simple HTTP/S get call using nodejs on CloudFront URL and it should work for you.

Comment: That means I can't use the JS library?

Comment: @jones that isn't what it means... but to answer this question correctly, we need to understand exactly what you are doing more clearly.  Typically, CloudFront is accessed directly by the browser, not by your application server.  There are many variations, but the first question is why your Node.js server is handling the payload.  You can use browser → CloudFront → S3 and avoid the need for a server to touch the data stream at all.  You can use pre-signed URLs if you need to control access.  Please see if you can edit the question to provide more detail about your choices so far.

Comment: I see, i have edited in my use case

Answer (score 0):

This can be tried by making few changes in the given configuration as below:

Change the piece of code:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  endpoint: CLOUDFRONT_URL
})
```

to

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
      "accessKeyId": "Access_Key",
      "secretAccessKey": "Secret_access_key",
      "s3BucketEndpoint": "true",
      "endpoint": "YourS3ENDPoint"
    })
```

This should help!

Comment: What about the CloudFront URL? "YourS3ENDPoint" - what to put there?

Comment: Yes. You can put your CloudFront URL. Got confused due to "I might have misunderstood the use case for Cloudfront." statement in your question. Hence generalized it.

Comment: I get a status code 403 with code "Forbidden" when attempting this.

Comment: Make sure your objects in the bucket are public. Also, the bucket policy must allow access to s3:GetObject.

Comment: Aha, normally I can download just fine without changing permissions but I have to if I want to use CloudFront? Seems like it's not worth to let everything go public in order to get a little faster download speed... Let me know if i misunderstood something

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a readStream, you could use the SDK to get a presigned URL for download. That way you don't need to pay extra for cloudfront.

Here is an example:

```
   const Aws = require('aws-sdk');
   const s3 = new Aws.S3();

   Aws.config.update({accessKeyId: 'accessKey created on IAM',
                      secretAccessKey: 'secretKey created on IAM',
                      region: 'default region'
                      });

   const download_url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
                                        Bucket: 'bucket of file',
                                        Key: 'filename of filepath within the bucket',
                                        Expires: 'case you need to expire the url (value in seconds)'})

console.log(download_url);
```

If this solved, let me know :)

Comment: Hmm, I'm interested in the CDN capabilities of CloudFront though?

Comment: How do I stream with this download_url?